# .NET Source Link: "Source not found" despite correct link

Tags: .net, sourcelink

I think I set up everything correctly.
My symbols are created and I configured Visual Studio after [this](https://aaronstannard.com/visual-studio-sourcelink-setup/) tutorial.
I can step into other libraries like JsonNet.

When I try to step into my code it tries to load the code from the correct path.
(I can access the desired file via this path in the internet browser.)

[image]

It starts downloading:

[image]

But then it fails with the message: "Source Not Found" although the path is correct!

[image]

What can be the reason?

**Edit 1:**
Add the source server debug messages under the Visual Studio Debugging Options:
[image]

Then I get the following error message:
SRCSRV: The module `'C:\Users\Administrator\.......\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\.....SectorGrid.dll' does not contain source server information.`

**Edit 2:**
I do not add the source link parameter mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/sourcelink?view=vs-2019). But I think this happens under the hood!? I do not get in touch with the mentioned json, described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/2020/diagnostics/source-link.md#source-link-json-schema). But I have an exact same link as described there within my .pdb file:
[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Comment: To tell the truth yes. It was nothing like a distinct single solution. A colleague of mine finally tested it in the same way, the week after and it worked. Are you stuck here as well? We don't have too much time but I could maybe ask my colleagues how it is done nowadays.

Comment: Yes I'm stuck, if you have a solution to bring me I'm interested !

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to enable the option "Enable Just My Code" in Debug → Options → Debugging → General

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Most tutorials (as the one linked in the question) even propose to explicitly disable this option when using Source Link.

Answer (score 0):

A similar experience here: for my machine, it works for one codebase and for the others not. On the device of a colleague, it works for both.

I'm the owner of both repositories, so a permission problem is unlikely. What confuses me: there is this dialog that appeared during the first time of debugging a *.cs file of a NuGet package.

[image]

Then it doesn't show up again. Maybe I have chosen the wrong answer when it appeared on my machine. How can the selection be reset, so that the dialog appears again?